# Entity framework function imports parameter types are reset upon model update from database

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a stored procedure in my database (running on SQL Server 2008 R2) that takes one of its parameters as a `tinyint`. On the Entity Framework (v5.0) model, using function imports for that stored procedure, the parameter is mapped by default to a `Byte`.

However, i've created a custom `enum` in that model to whom i set the type of the function import's parameter that was originally `Byte`. The underlying data type for that `enum` is `Byte` as well. The problem is that, whenever i update the model from the database, the parameter type is reverted back to `Byte`, even if there were no changes at all in the database affecting the said stored procedure.

Is this a known EF bug or am i missing something?

Comment: I know this is old but I'm running into this too even now and this question is the only thing I've seen so far that even references the issue.  Did you ever get a real answer?  Currently I have a function import that requires me to go update one of the parameters to an enum each time I update the model from the database.

Comment: Sorry @EricH, I haven't got any answers that solve my issue. Not surprising though, as Microsoft recommends moving away from model-first edmx style of working with EF.

Comment: Bummer, I gave up on the mapping after I couldn't take the resetting anymore and resorted to casting my enum to an int when calling the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately currently Update Model from the Database overwrites all the customizations made to the model.

Comment: Do you mean customizations related to stored procedures only or regardless of their type? I've only noticed this problem with stored procedures, other customizations such as table splitting, column-to-enum mappings and many others are not dropped (unless tables are removed and re-added).

Comment: AFAIR the model is basically created from scratch and overwrites customizations. I don't remember at the moment if there are any exceptions to this. Btw is it a stored procedure or a table valued function?

Comment: It is a stored procedure, with multiple input parameters.